# Выбор табы в Data Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getSettings();

    $("#tabs li a").click(function () {
        getSettings();
    });
});

function getSettings() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'list_settings.php?part=global&view=json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var tab = ($("#tabs li.active a").attr('href'));
            console.log(tab);
        }
    });
}
```

Начал делать табы и столкнулся с проблемой - когда клацаю по табе, то переменной tab присваивается не значение не из той табы на которую я нажимаю, и которая по идее становится активной, а той, что была активной до этого.

Comment: Проблема скорее всего в том месте, где вы класс задаёте/снимаете, этого нет в примере. + стоит передавать `index` таба в `getSettings()`, тк аякс прилететь может позже, чем вы переключите таб.

Comment: я пробовал передавать. то же самое

Comment: А на первую часть моего комментария что скажите? я так понял вы вообще не меняете класс active на нужный таб и соответственно загружается информация всегда только в первый таб

Comment: он задаётся и снимается автоматически вроде. по крайней мере в просмотре кода он ставится  снимается по щелчку

Comment: Там плагин чтоли?

Comment: Artem Gorlachev, что такое $(this).index()?

Comment: индекс li в данном случае, кстати я ошибся, this это ссылка, должно быть `$(this).parent().index()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getSettings(0);

    $("#tabs li a").click(function () {
        $("#tabs li.active").removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        getSettings($(this).index());
    });
});

function getSettings(i) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'list_settings.php?part=global&view=json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var tab = ($("#tabs li:eq('+i+') a").attr('href'));
            console.log(tab);
        }
    });
}
```